# fbgraph error code

Tags: facebook, error-handling, error-code, facebook-graph-api

Does anyone know where can I find all the error code and error type for FBGraph? While handling error, I want to check what error FBGraph throws (like: duplicate post error, access token expire error) and take action accordingly. (I a working on Ruby On Rails 3)

I referred the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/fb_graph/1.9.1/FbGraph/Unauthorized), but it doesn't list out the code and type of all the errors. Where can I find these error codes?

Thanks... :)

Answer (score 3):

This has long been a problem with using the Graph API.  There's no documentation anywhere as to all the possible errors that you can receive.  Additionally there are errors that you receive randomly that don't occur when you make the same request again (ie [bugs](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=16820)).

A lot of the Graph API seems to have an underlying structure that makes FQL queries.  So, when those FQL based queries throw an error you can find the code here:  http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/Error_codes#FQL_Errors